# Left sidebar cut off by browser window

Tags: html, css, wordpress, sidebar

This is my website:
http://www.jrbaldwin.com

I'm having a problem of my left sidebar getting cutoff when the window is reduced past a certain width. I assume it's a simple CSS issue, but I am not sure.

Comment: My answer clearly identified the problem at you asked about, was the answer not clear or did it not solve your problem ? If so please elaborate so that I may help better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove Position fixed and negative margin

```
#sidebar {
border-bottom: 0 solid #E7E7E7;
border-right: 0 solid #E7E7E7;
color: #59454F;
float: left;
font-size: 13px;
width: 132px;
```

}

---

so you can use different way, replace these 3 Classes:

```
#header {
    border-bottom: 0 solid #E7E7E7;
    height: 65px;
    margin-left: 135px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#outer {
    border-bottom: 0 solid #E7E7E7;
    border-left: 0 solid #E7E7E7;
    border-right: 0 solid #E7E7E7;
    border-style: solid;
    line-height: 1.4;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1055px;
}

#sidebar {
    border-bottom: 0 solid #E7E7E7;
    border-right: 0 solid #E7E7E7;
    color: #59454F;
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 0 -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 132px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I remove these, it makes the sidebar inline with the thumbnail columns. I want it to remain outside to the left of the thumbnails.

Answer (score 1):

There is a margin-left of -149px on the #sidebar. Setting this to 0px will fix your issue.